# Space Straw - Pressures and Possibility

Tags: pressure, earth, atmospheric-science, fluid-statics

So, Thinking Again :/

If we built a tunnel, out into space far beyond our atmosphere and opened it up

Would the resulting differences in pressure then effectively suck out the interior of our atmosphere??

[image: earth]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.
[This](http://www.askamathematician.com/2014/11/q-what-would-happen-if-there-was-a-giant-straw-connecting-the-earths-atmosphere-right-above-the-ground-to-space/) provides a good explanation, and I would recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=im7DzMr8Ygs) video by Vsauce.

The longer answer is that a straw doesn't provide anything special in this situation, it is just a column of atmosphere surrounded by a bit of plastic.
The pressure would vary with altitude inside the straw just like it does normally.
So there should be no reason why the atmosphere would suddenly decide to start flowing up out of this straw into space.

Comment: Yes i agree:
however if the the tunnel (so Wider than a straw (assuming volume will be a contributing factor - if the tunnel is blocked and then opened, would the sudden movement of pressure then work like a syphon ?? :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer though ill have a look at that link now !